# Wired connection stops working suddenly

Tags: wireless, windows, internet, connection

I have Ubuntu 12.04. I was downloading something via Aria... and then it suddenly stopped. There was no connection to the Internet.

I tried to ping the host but there was no reply. Also tried to ping the route 192.168.250.1 but there was no reply. I got a message saying 'Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced internal error'.

I restarted system but nothing was sorted out.
The wired connection 'establishes' but I am not able to use Internet or ping either to host/route/8.8.8.8.

The wireless is working fine and it does connect to Internet.
I have a static IP address for a wired connection and it connects to Internet on Windows OS installed on the same laptop with same IP settings.

Please suggest how I can get my wired connection to start working properly again.

Answer (score 0):

Try a DHCP address for the wired connection maybe, I know that whenever I try to set a static address I cant connect to anything.

Cheers

P.S I know this may not be an answer but where else am I suppose to post this, there is no comment button :/

Comment: hi thanks for ur response. well i never able to establish connection with dynamic address on my available network!! and here it is not clear how SUDDENLY i loose connection which was working in those configurations..Here i am able to establish a connection with few choices of IP addresses i have but no access to internet.. probably router starts to block my particular system's physical address all of a sudden.(My illusion!).